# how to call a rest api to fetch json and use it in next variable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am building a react js based shopping application .I used a sample application from https://codepen.io/paulkim/pen/oZLavq , I want to fetch the product json from an api call. Any help .I tried adding jquery and using the api call :

```
const { reduxthunk } = ('redux-thunk');
//const middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware());
//example
var return_first = async function () {

  var settings = {
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
  };
  var tmp = null;

 await $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    tmp = response.Items;
    console.log(response.Items)
  });
  return tmp;
}();
```

//need stock value from previous jquery call

```
const initialState = {
  cart: [],
  stock: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'TC 2017 LS',
      description: 'VC FlexLight Jersey with spot sublimated Team Canada 2017 logo, from our Team Canada Collection.',
      price: 34.95,
      count: 12,
      img: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0340/2849/products/TC2017_LS_Mens_grande.jpg?v=1485541617',
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'TC 2017 Shorts',
      description: 'VC FlexLight Shorts with spot sublimated Team Canada 2017 logo, from our Team Canada Collection.',
      price: 25.00,
      count: 7,
      img: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0340/2849/products/TC2017_Shorts_White_grande.jpg?v=1485541580',
    }]}
```

Comment: Can you place your code of what you have tried?

Comment: added the code what i added.In console.log i am getting the output

Comment: here in the actual code i tried using my variable instead of the stock

Answer (score 0):

At the render function i used the promise to fetch the data and render the product element dynamically .

```
var temp=return_first;
//console.log(temp);
//console.log(temp);
apidata=temp.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Some User token"

// INITIAL STATE
const initialState = {
  cart: [],
  stock: result

};

  const store = Redux.createStore(reducers, initialState);
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Provider, { store: store },
    React.createElement(App, null)),document.getElementById('app'));
  return result;
});
```